# How get the sequences properly indented with ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

With the following data

```
from ruamel import yaml
data = {1: {1:[{1:1,2:2},{1:1,2:2}], 2:2}, 2: 42}
```

I get an incorrect indentation for the sequence

```
>>> print yaml.round_trip_dump(data)
1:
  1:
  - 1: 1
    2: 2
  - 1: 1
    2: 2
  2: 2
2: 42
```

Which cannot be folded on Notepad++. However with the proper indent it works:

Bad:

[image: Bad Indent]

Good:

[image: Good Indent]

I have tried to use `block_seq_indent=2`:

```
>>> print yaml.round_trip_dump(data, block_seq_indent=2)
1:
  1:
    - 1: 1
    2: 2
    - 1: 1
    2: 2
  2: 2
2: 42
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `ruamel.yaml` documentation, although generally lacking, says the following about [`offset`](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail.html?highlight=block_seq_indent#indentation-of-block-sequences) of the dash within the indent:

> If the offset equals sequence, there is not enough room for the dash and the space that has to follow it. In that case the element itself would normally be pushed to the next line (and older versions of ruamel.yaml did so). But this is prevented from happening. However the indent level is what is used for calculating the cumulative indent for deeper levels and specifying sequence=3 resp. offset=2, might give correct, but counter intuitive results.
>
> **It is best to always have sequence** >= offset + 2 **but this is not enforced**. Depending on your structure, not following this advice **might lead to invalid output**.

By default `indent` (both for mappings and for sequences) equals 2, if you do:

```
import sys
from ruamel import yaml

data = {1: {1:[{1:1,2:2},{1:1,2:2}], 2:2}, 2: 42}

yml = yaml.YAML()
yml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you get:

```
1:
  1:
    - 1: 1
      2: 2
    - 1: 1
      2: 2
  2: 2
2: 42
```

With the old API, that you use in your question, you cannot do the different indent for mappings and sequences in a trivial way (you need to subclass the Emitter, and on post `__init__` of the base class, set the values). And with older versions of ruamel.yaml this was not possible at all.

This only works with the default (round-trip, i.e. `typ='rt'`) dumper, but does work with both the normal Python `dict` resp. `list` (e.g. from `YAML(typ='safe').load(....)`) and the
more convulated subclasses thereof used when doing `YAML().load(....)`

(the above requires ruamel.yaml>=0.15.30)

Comment: Unfortunately with a indent of 4 I cannot use notepad++ to fold my YAML. That said the YAML specification recommend an indent of 2

Comment: With the updated `.indent()` you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: Thank you for specifying "with the default dumper".  Spent quite some time wondering why changing the configuration of my safe `YAML` class wasn't working.