# How to keep original indentations in YML file after section deletion

Tags: python, yaml

I am using Python script to remove specific sections in YML file, which is schema of source tables for DBT in format like:

```yaml
models:
  - name: model1
    columns:
      - name: ID
        description: user_id
        data_type: INT64
      - name: ATTR
        description: attribute_name
        data_type: INT64
  - name: model2
    columns:
      - name: USER
        description: username
```

and when i am deleting one section let's say "- name: model1" using this function:

```py
def remove_section_from_yml(yml_path, section_name):
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

    with open(yml_path, 'r') as f:
        data= yaml.load(f)

        for i, model in enumerate(data['models']):
            if 'name' in model and model['name'] == section_name:
                del data['models'][i]
                break
        
    with open(yml_path, 'w') as f:
        yaml.preserve_quotes = True
        yaml.dump(data, f)
```

and it is working properly as removing section which I do not need, but in the output file indents are not correct and looks like this:

```yaml
models:
- name: model2
  columns:
    - name: USER
      description: username
```

It is moving section with model name completely to the left without indent and I don't know how to resolve it. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get the sequences properly indented with ruamel.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388701/how-get-the-sequences-properly-indented-with-ruamel-yaml)

Comment: Note: The output you are getting is actually correct as well and is equivalent to the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the reason you want keep the original format is easy to do diff when compare with different version.

There are three possible solutions I could think of. Preferred solution A over B and cautious to use C.

### Solution A

The common way of working for manipulate yaml are in 3 steps.

- Load yaml file into native object form
- Change the content in object form
- Dump into yaml file from object form

Use exact same yaml library with the auto formater of IDE or the original yaml library which created the yaml file. Find and use the same configuration and dump it.

[Here is a link to source code of dbt use to dump yaml](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/dc3f60801e2019e3b012fedf313b4f92cd98fa14/core/dbt/graph/cli.py#L147)

> More often than not, the version also matter

### Solution B

If hard to figure out exact yaml library, or the exact configuration.

Then we could create a hook to automatically reformat before commit the code.
In this way we always keep the same format.

### Solution C

Treat the yaml file as plain text format. Manipulate as text file, instead of yaml file.

> CAUTIOUS, This might break the yaml format.